# Adding a +15/-15 V chip on a 0-5 V board

Tags: design

**General Question:**

I would like to integrate a specialized chip that requires symmetrical power +15, 0 and -15 V to operate on a 0 V (GND) / +5 V (VCC) board I designed. If possible, I would also like to support 3V – 5.5 V power supplies.

I am pretty sure it should be possible, but I do not know how to do that (I have very little knowledge in electronics) and searches turned up nothing.

**More precise question:**

The part I would like to use accepts from ±12V to ±22V power supply, so the supply does not need to be exactly 15 V. Also, the part includes an internal precision 10 V reference, thus, the power supply of the chip does not need to be outstandingly stable. The 5 V supply I have on my board is stabilized.

Below are the characteristics of the part given by the manufacturer:

> Supply: ±22V  Input Current, Continuous: 40mA  Input Current
>   Momentary, 0.1s: 250mA, 1% Duty Cycle  Common-Mode Input Voltage,
>   Continuous: ±40V

I am mainly interested in learning, so any explanation will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much for reading me and for your guidance.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, plus, it is not really a question, but I would be interested in using preferably cheap parts.

Comment: Can you start with a +15V supply input, rather than +5V?  Or even a little bit higher, +24V wouldn't be too high.  If you can make that choice, that open some options, which make the design of the power converters simpler.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thanks for your reply. Actually, I would very much avoid resort to this solution because, eventually, the whole system will be battery powered.

Comment: What will be the battery voltage?

Comment: Selected battery voltage is 9 V currently (regulated down to 5 V) but shoud evolve to 4.5 (regulated down to 3.3 V).

Comment: I not know the power requirements you need to fulfill or price, but maybe might try the LT3571 from Linear Technologies or any similar integrated circuit.
[Here](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3571) you can look for this product.

Comment: How much current does the +/- 15V part need?

Comment: Momentarily: **Current Momentary, 0.1s: 250mA, 1% Duty Cycle** ; Continuuously : 40 mA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's xmas I'd be looking for an off-the-shelf-and-very-lazy solution and my 1st port of call would be Traco and the [TMA](http://www.tracopower.com/fileadmin/medien/dokumente/pdf/datasheets/tma.pdf) series of power supply modules.

The TMA 0515D can provide +/-15V (isolated) from a 5V dc supply. It's a 1 watt "solution" and can deliver up to +/- 35mA to your load at an efficiency of about 80%. You can also get a +/-12V output version too.

It's about 2cm long, 1cm high and about 0.7cm wide. It's an unregulated version so it does need a fairly constant 5V power supply but there are others in the range that work across a variety of input voltages and some provide output power up to over 30 watts.

I'm beginning to sound like a sales man now!!

They cost £3.50 from [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/tracopower/tma-0515d/converter-dc-dc-1w-15v-0-04a/dp/1007516?Ntt=TMA0515D)

If you want this power supply to work with input voltages from 3V to 5.5v you would need to introduce a boost-buck converter to produce a stable 5V rail to feed it. Alternatively use a version of the Traco with a 12V input (TMA 1215D) and use a 12V boost(only) converter to power it from 3V to 5.5V. I would go this route because it's simpler (and probably cheaper) to design a boost circuit than designing a dual flyback switching converter.

Comment: Nice ! I have seen TRACO also provides 2 and 3 W parts, which would be able to supply the required current. However, they are really expansive !

Answer (score 1):

You could build a boost converter, but it might be hard on your batteries: 250ma @ 15V will require at least 750ma @ 5V, and therefore you ought to expect an amp from the batteries. If you want decent battery lifetime with this part on the board give it its own battery pack with a buck converter producing 5V for the logic.

Comment: The specs say : **Current Momentary, 0.1s: 250mA** but also : **Continuuously : 40 mA**. So I would only need to provide 40 mA or so. What would happen if I go with a solution capable of providing 80 mA? The part is a 4-20 mA current loop reciever. Can I just go along with a capacitor ?